# SQL Server - Como establecer un día para un listado de fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cordial saludo,

Acudo a ustedes ya que tengo un listado de fechas como el siguiente

| # | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1316 | 2022-03-01 |
| 1316 | 2022-04-03 |
| 1316 | 2022-05-27 |

necesito establecer ejemplo el día 14 a cada una de las fechas anteriores, pero hasta el momento no he podido encontrar como realizar lo que requiero con SQL.

Muchas gracias y quedo muy al pendiente.

Cordialmente.

Comment: Puedes seleccionar solo el año y mes y le concatenas el 14 al final.

Comment: Hola.... no queda muy clara la pregunta. Ese listado es el contenido de una tabla? Qué es el 1316? una clave foránea? si es así, podrías hacer un algo como esto: `UPDATE Listado SET fecha = DATEFROMPARTS (Year(fecha), Month(fecha), 14) WHERE fk = 1316`... esto funcionará en un SQL Server 2012 o superior.

Answer (score 0):

Perfecto con los dos comentarios anteriores puede realizar lo que necesitaba dejo el codigo para mejor comprensión

```
declare @fechInicial date 
declare @fechFinal date
declare @id_spot int
declare @dia int


SET @fechInicial = '2022-03-02'
SET @fechFinal = '2022-07-02'
SET @id_spot = 1316
SET @dia = 14

BEGIN
    SELECT @fechInicial, @fechFinal;
        WITH FECHAS(fecha) AS (
            SELECT @fechInicial fecha
                UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(month,3, fecha) fecha
                    FROM FECHAS
                    WHERE fecha < @fechFinal
            )
            select @id_spot AS '#', DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(fecha), Month(fecha), @dia) fecha from FECHAS 
        OPTION (MaxRecursion 0)

END
```

Muchas gracias